# instafeed response not appearing on page

Tags: instagram, instafeedjs

I getting no results on my instafeed.js page, however, the instagram api is returning images. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Instagram Portfolio</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/instafeed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <section class="instagram-wrap">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="instagram-content">
                        <h3>Latest Photos</h3>
                        <div class="row photos-wrap">
                        <!-- Instafeed target div -->
                        <div id="instafeed"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
    $(function() {

    //Set up instafeed
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        clientId: 'my_client_id',
        target: 'instafeed',
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'testlaura', 
        links: true,
        limit: 8,
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        filter: function(image) {
            return image.user_has_liked;
        },
        template: '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="photo-box"><div class="image-wrap"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}"></a><div class="likes">{{likes}} Likes</div></div><div class="description">{{caption}}<div class="date">{{model.date}}</div></div></div></div>'
    });
    feed.run();

});
```

"lauratest" is the tag I used on some photos on a different account.

But why is nothing appearing on my page? I'm not getting any console errors, and the instafeed and app.js files are definitely being read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image.user_has_liked` filter only with `accessToken`. The filter is less with `clientId`, because there is not an `auth user` which `like` will be taken in this filter.

You may check it by [https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/testlaura/media/recent/?client_id={{CLIENT_ID}}](https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/testlaura/media/recent/?client_id=)

So, first you have to get an `accessToken`, if you want to use this `filter`.